# CSS rotation animation stop in place

Tags: css

I have the class .orbit that triggers the orbit animation. I remove the class to stop the rotation. That resets the element to its original position.

Is there a way to stop the rotation animation in its tracks, leaving the element where it is?

Currently getting the position and setting it to that, but it's not perfect.

https://jsfiddle.net/f4hnz2va/2/

```
#errordot{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-size:40px;
}
#errorsun{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
.orbit {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-name:orbit;
    -webkit-animation-duration:5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
from { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) }
to { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) }
}
@-moz-keyframes orbit {
from { -moz-transform:rotate(0deg) }
to { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg) }
}
```

Comment: My updated fiddle, with the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/f4hnz2va/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is not "stop" the orbit animation, but "pause" it, using CSS3 `animation-play-state` property. If you want to pause it forever and not resume again, a mark variable (such as "hasPaused") can be applied.

Sample jsfiddle can be found at:
https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/1kb8cm7j/1/